# Why is stacklayout content getting overlapped?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a content page with a scroll view, stack layout, carousel view and some labels. When the stack layout content gets enough elements (as shown in the example by duplicating elements), everything seems to start 'layering' on top of the carousel view. The image doesn't seem to be scaling, just being cutoff. I'm relatively inexperienced with XAML so I'm likely doing something wrong.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding imgs}" 
                             x:Name="CarouselImgs">
               <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <Image HeightRequest="200" 
                            Aspect="AspectFill" 
                            Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>

                   </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
               </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView>
            <Label TextColor="Blue" 
                   Text="{Binding SellerName, 
                   StringFormat='Seller: {0}'}" 
                   x:Name="lblSeller"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ItemID, StringFormat='Item #{0}'}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat='Title: {0}'}" 
                   HeightRequest="15" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using this plugin: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView? If so, I recommend you to set the `cv:CarouselView`'s `HeightRequest` directly to show the `CarouselView`.

You said **The image just being cutoff** because you set the `Aspect` to `AspectFill`. It will Scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

If you want to scale the image to fit your image's size, you can try `Fill`.

Comment: It was definitely the HeightRequest property....setting that larger was the key. Thank you.